# Listening keydown events from a pdf embedded on an iframe react

Tags: reactjs, iframe, addeventlistener, keydown, hotkeys

I am developing a web page where I need to fill some forms with information provided from a Pdf file. For this, I used Iframe to show the pdf and its content. To move around the forms, I am using hotkeys but when I focus on the pdf file the hotkeys does not work. That is why i try adding an event listener on the react component where the i frame is but it does not work.

```
const Viewer = () => {
  const iframe = useRef()
  
    useEffect(() => {       
      function onKeyup(e) {        
        if (e.key ) alert('you pressed a key')
        const message = "you pressed a key" 
        window.parent.postMessage(message, '*');          
      }
      document.getElementById('iframe').contentWindow.document.addEventListener('keydown', onKeyup);
      return () =>  document.getElementById('iframe').contentWindow.document.removeEventListener('keydown', onKeyup);
    }, []);
  

 

  return (
    <div className="h-full w-full ">
      <iframe id='iframe'
             
            className="h-full w-full"
            src={file}
            type='application/pdf'
            title='title'
          />
    </div>
  )
}

export default Viewer
```

Comment: Did you ever get this resolved? I need the same principal i.e. hotkeys to navigate from one component to the other but because my viewer (pdf.js) is in an iframe, it does not propagate the event back to the main form, well, pdf.js does not even generate keydown event for that matter, so still researching this part.